# Java Default Authentication vs arguments for proxy

Tags: java, proxy, arguments

I've searched a lot for this topic, but didn't understand exactly why if I try to consume a web service in my java application I would fail without implementing with this snippet as well:

```
final String authUser = "myUser";
    final String authPassword ="******";
    Authenticator.setDefault(
       new Authenticator() {
          public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
             return new PasswordAuthentication(
                   authUser, authPassword.toCharArray());
          }
       }
    );
```

...I don't like to "sculpt" my credentials here, or in a property file.
i'd prefer to use the "Run as" vm arguments...so if I comment the code above and run my app with:

```
-Dhttps.proxyHost=proxy.test.it 
-Dhttp.proxyPort=3128 
-Dhttp.proxyUsername=myUser  
-Dhttps.proxyPassword=**** 
-Danypoint.platform.proxy_username=myUser 
-Danypoint.platform.proxy_password=**** 
-Danypoint.platform.proxy_host=proxy.test.it 
-Danypoint.platform.proxy_port=3128 
-Djava.net.useSystemProxies=true
-Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=...
```

or...

```
    System.setProperty("http.proxyUser", authUser);
    System.setProperty("http.proxyPassword", authPassword);
    System.setProperty("http.nonProxyHosts","myHost");
    System.setProperty("useSystemProxies","true");
```

it won't work. I really don't get it.

Thanks for support!

Comment: you can always do `String authUser = System.getProperty("http.proxyUser")` so that it's value is not hardcoded in code, but read from cmd line

Comment: sure, but it doesn't work! pls read my sentences. If and ONLY IF I put the firt java script, the call won't fail...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to achieve, but if you pass in your data through the vm arugments like this

```
-Dhttp.proxyUsername=myUser  
-Dhttps.proxyPassword=****
```

You would access the data like this.

```
String authUser = System.getProperty("http.proxyUser");
```

Comment: This way *does* work. You're not using it right.  Do not declare ```authUser``` twice. (You've marked it as ```final ...``` in your example. If you do as described above, your application will work as you would like it to.

Comment: And if I would like to totally avoid that piece of code? It's not possible to let it work without that java snippet? As I said, I've commented that part...

Comment: You want to avoid setting the username inside of a variable such as ```authUser```? What piece of code exactly do you not want to have there.`

Comment: Pls don't consider the variable thing. I would like to run successfully my code only using args...without initial snippet. just passing values to vm.

Comment: That won't work. PasswordAuthentication needs to know the username and password, and you have to tell it what those are. It will not look for them in the args.